# java PING PONG capturar teclas

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un juego de ping pong en java. El proyecto esta recién empezado así que de momento únicamente se pueden mover las 2 raquetas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es a la hora de mover las raquetas. La primera se mueve arriba y abajo con las teclas W y S respectivamente, la segunda raqueta se mueve con las teclas de dirección arriba y abajo respectivamente. Las raquetas se mueven correctamente si solo se mueve una a la vez; sin embargo a la hora de mover ambas al mismo tiempo una detiene a la otra. Quisiera saber como podría hacer que se movieran de forma independiente para que una no afecte el movimiento de la otra.

```
package juego.ping.pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JuegoPingPong extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    // componentes swing
    private JMenuBar jMBMenu;
    private JMenu jMJuego;
    private JMenu jMPuntuaciones;
    private JMenuItem jMIJuegoNuevo;
    private JMenuItem jMIPuntuaciones;

    private JLabel jLLinea1;  
    private JLabel jLLinea2;
    private JLabel jLLineaPunteada;
    private JLabel jLRaqueta1;
    private JLabel jLRaqueta2;
    private JLabel jLPelota;
    private JLabel jLAvatarJ1;
    private JLabel jLAvatarJ2;
    private JLabel jLPuntuacionJ1;
    private JLabel jLPuntuacionJ2;
    private JLabel jLVs;
    private JLabel jLFondo;

    // variables internas
    private String Jugador1;
    private String Jugador2;
    private int tipoJuego;
    private int puntuacionJ1;
    private int puntuacionJ2;

    // ActionListener para los menos

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getSource() == jMIJuegoNuevo) 
        {
            System.out.println("juego");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == jMIPuntuaciones) 
        {
            System.out.println("puntos");
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public JuegoPingPong()
    {
        super("The Cerdo´s Pong");
        setLayout(null);

        initComponents();

        // Menus
        jMJuego = new JMenu("Juego");
        jMJuego.setForeground( Color.WHITE );

        jMIJuegoNuevo = new JMenuItem( "Juego Nuevo" );     
        jMIJuegoNuevo.addActionListener(this);
        jMJuego.add(jMIJuegoNuevo);

        jMPuntuaciones = new JMenu("Puntuaciones");   
        jMPuntuaciones.setForeground( Color.WHITE );

        jMIPuntuaciones = new JMenuItem("Puntuacion Total");    
        jMIPuntuaciones.addActionListener(this);
        jMPuntuaciones.add( jMIPuntuaciones );

        jMBMenu = new JMenuBar();
        jMBMenu.setLocation( 0,0 );
        jMBMenu.setVisible( true );
        jMBMenu.setSize( 1244, 20 );
        jMBMenu.setBackground( new Color( 0, 15, 22) );
        add( jMBMenu );

        jMBMenu.add( jMJuego );
        jMBMenu.add( jMPuntuaciones );

        // labels 

        jLVs = new JLabel();
        jLVs.setIcon(new ImageIcon (  
getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/vs.png" ) ) );  
        jLVs.setLocation( 607, 65 );
        jLVs.setSize( 30,  29 );
        add(jLVs);

        jLLinea1 = new JLabel();
        jLLinea1.setIcon(new ImageIcon (  
getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/linea.png" ) ) ); 
        jLLinea1.setSize( 1166, 20 );
        jLLinea1.setLocation( 39,100 );
        add(jLLinea1);

        jLLinea2 = new JLabel();
        jLLinea2.setIcon(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/linea.png")));
        jLLinea2.setSize(1166, 20);
        jLLinea2.setLocation(39, 630);
        add(jLLinea2);

        jLLineaPunteada = new JLabel();
        jLLineaPunteada.setIcon(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/linea punteada.png")));
        jLLineaPunteada.setSize(22, 524);
        jLLineaPunteada.setLocation(611, 112);
        add(jLLineaPunteada);

        jLAvatarJ1 = new JLabel();
        jLAvatarJ1.setSize( 72,70 );
        jLAvatarJ1.setIcon(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/brown.png")));
        jLAvatarJ1.setLocation( 500, 25  );
        add(jLAvatarJ1);

        jLAvatarJ2 = new JLabel();
        jLAvatarJ2.setSize(72, 70);
        jLAvatarJ2.setIcon(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/lobillo.png")));
        jLAvatarJ2.setLocation(700, 25);
        add(jLAvatarJ2);


        jLRaqueta1 = new JLabel();
        jLRaqueta1.setOpaque( true );
        jLRaqueta1.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        jLRaqueta1.setSize( 31, 102 );
        jLRaqueta1.setLocation( 30, 345 );
        add(jLRaqueta1);

        jLRaqueta2 = new JLabel();
        jLRaqueta2.setOpaque( true );
        jLRaqueta2.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        jLRaqueta2.setSize(31, 102);
        jLRaqueta2.setLocation(1200, 345);
        add(jLRaqueta2);

        // Fondo

        jLFondo = new JLabel();
        jLFondo.setSize( 1244,  690 );
        jLFondo.setOpaque( true );
        jLFondo.setLocation( 0,0 );
        jLFondo.setBackground( new Color( 0,15,22 ) );
        add( jLFondo );


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JuegoPingPong juego = new JuegoPingPong();
        juego.setVisible(true);
        juego.setSize(1244, 715);
        juego.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        juego.setResizable(false);
        juego.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private void initComponents() {
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
            {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }

        });
    }

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
    {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) 
        {
            jLRaqueta1.setLocation( jLRaqueta1.getX(), jLRaqueta1.getY() - 
10);
        }

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) 
        {
            jLRaqueta1.setLocation(jLRaqueta1.getX(), jLRaqueta1.getY() + 
10);
        }

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) 
        {
            jLRaqueta2.setLocation(jLRaqueta2.getX(), jLRaqueta2.getY() - 
10);
        }

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) 
        {
            jLRaqueta2.setLocation(jLRaqueta2.getX(), jLRaqueta2.getY() + 
10);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Creo que lo suyo sería hacer el movimiento de las raquetas con hilos. Tengo java bastante olvidado, pero creo que en los hilos esta tu solución.

Comment: En java para hacer 2 cosas a la vez no tienenes más remedio que ir a hilos Ejemplo: http://dhw.umh.es/alex-bia/teaching/PC/material/hilos_tutorial-java/cap10-2.htm Lo más aconsejable es que ambos hilos capturen el keyPressed, solo que el primero sólo tratará la W y la S y el otro las flechas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la solución a tu problema. He generado una clase EventSelector encargada de manejar los eventos de click sobre la pantalla.

Si el evento de click se encuentra entre los permitidos y no ha sido registrado previamente, lo añade a una lista sincronizada de eventos. Cuando el evento deja de existir. Algo que se controla en el método, keyReleased. Ese evento se borra de la lista.

Por último he metido los cursores en una clase encargada de actualizar las posiciones para que el código sea más sencillo de mantener.

La velocidad de actualización de los cursores se maneja con el tiempo establecido en Thread.sleep(). En este caso es de 20 milisegundos

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TesTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    public class EventSelector implements Runnable, KeyListener{

        Raqueta left;
        Raqueta right;
        List<KeyEvent> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

        EventSelector(Raqueta left, Raqueta right){
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20L);
                    if(!list.isEmpty()){
                        for (KeyEvent event : list) {
                            if(left.isInRaqueta(event.getKeyCode())){
                                left.formKeyPressed(event);
                            }else if(right.isInRaqueta(event.getKeyCode())){
                                right.formKeyPressed(event);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if(containsEvent(arg0)<0){
                list.add(arg0);
            }
        }

        private int containsEvent(KeyEvent arg0) {
            int pos = 0;
            for (KeyEvent event : list) {
                if(event.getKeyCode()==arg0.getKeyCode()){
                    return pos;
                }
                pos++;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            list.remove(containsEvent(arg0));
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }

    }

    // componentes swing
    private JMenuBar jMBMenu;
    private JMenu jMJuego;
    private JMenu jMPuntuaciones;
    private JMenuItem jMIJuegoNuevo;
    private JMenuItem jMIPuntuaciones;

    private JLabel jLLinea1;  
    private JLabel jLLinea2;
    private JLabel jLLineaPunteada;
    private JLabel jLRaqueta1;
    private JLabel jLRaqueta2;
    private JLabel jLPelota;
    private JLabel jLAvatarJ1;
    private JLabel jLAvatarJ2;
    private JLabel jLPuntuacionJ1;
    private JLabel jLPuntuacionJ2;
    private JLabel jLVs;
    private JLabel jLFondo;

    // variables internas
    private String Jugador1;
    private String Jugador2;
    private int tipoJuego;
    private int puntuacionJ1;
    private int puntuacionJ2;

    private EventSelector selector;

    // ActionListener para los menos

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if (e.getSource() == jMIJuegoNuevo) 
        {
            System.out.println("juego");
        }

        if (e.getSource() == jMIPuntuaciones) 
        {
            System.out.println("puntos");
        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public TesTest(Raqueta left, Raqueta right)
    {
        super("The Cerdo´s Pong");
        setLayout(null);

        selector = new EventSelector(left, right);
        left.addToFrame(this);
        right.addToFrame(this);
        new Thread(selector).start();

        // Menus
        jMJuego = new JMenu("Juego");
        jMJuego.setForeground( Color.WHITE );

        jMIJuegoNuevo = new JMenuItem( "Juego Nuevo" );     
        jMIJuegoNuevo.addActionListener(this);
        jMJuego.add(jMIJuegoNuevo);

        jMPuntuaciones = new JMenu("Puntuaciones");   
        jMPuntuaciones.setForeground( Color.WHITE );

        jMIPuntuaciones = new JMenuItem("Puntuacion Total");    
        jMIPuntuaciones.addActionListener(this);
        jMPuntuaciones.add( jMIPuntuaciones );

        jMBMenu = new JMenuBar();
        jMBMenu.setLocation( 0,0 );
        jMBMenu.setVisible( true );
        jMBMenu.setSize( 1244, 20 );
        jMBMenu.setBackground( new Color( 0, 15, 22) );
        add( jMBMenu );

        jMBMenu.add( jMJuego );
        jMBMenu.add( jMPuntuaciones );

        // labels 

        jLVs = new JLabel();
        jLVs.setIcon(new ImageIcon ( getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/vs.png" ) ) );  
        jLVs.setLocation( 607, 65 );
        jLVs.setSize( 30,  29 );
        add(jLVs);

        jLLinea1 = new JLabel();
        jLLinea1.setIcon(new ImageIcon ( getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/linea.png" ) ) ); 
        jLLinea1.setSize( 1166, 20 );
        jLLinea1.setLocation( 39,100 );
        add(jLLinea1);

        jLLinea2 = new JLabel();
        jLLinea2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/linea.png")));
        jLLinea2.setSize(1166, 20);
        jLLinea2.setLocation(39, 630);
        add(jLLinea2);

        jLLineaPunteada = new JLabel();
        jLLineaPunteada.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/linea punteada.png")));
        jLLineaPunteada.setSize(22, 524);
        jLLineaPunteada.setLocation(611, 112);
        add(jLLineaPunteada);

        jLAvatarJ1 = new JLabel();
        jLAvatarJ1.setSize( 72,70 );
        jLAvatarJ1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/brown.png")));
        jLAvatarJ1.setLocation( 500, 25  );
        add(jLAvatarJ1);

        jLAvatarJ2 = new JLabel();
        jLAvatarJ2.setSize(72, 70);
        jLAvatarJ2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Imagenes/lobillo.png")));
        jLAvatarJ2.setLocation(700, 25);
        add(jLAvatarJ2);

        // Fondo

        jLFondo = new JLabel();
        jLFondo.setSize( 1244,  690 );
        jLFondo.setOpaque( true );
        jLFondo.setLocation( 0,0 );
        jLFondo.setBackground( new Color( 0,15,22 ) );
        add( jLFondo );

        addKeyListener(selector);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Raqueta left = new Raqueta(30, 345, KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        Raqueta right = new Raqueta(1200, 345, KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);

        TesTest juego = new TesTest(left,right);

        juego.setVisible(true);
        juego.setSize(1244, 715);
        juego.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        juego.setResizable(false);
        juego.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}

class Raqueta{

    private JLabel raqueta;
    private int up;
    private int down;

    public Raqueta(int x, int y, int up, int down){
        raqueta = new JLabel();
        raqueta.setOpaque( true );
        raqueta.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        raqueta.setSize( 31, 102 );
        raqueta.setLocation( x, y );
        this.up = up;
        this.down = down;
    }

    public void addToFrame(TesTest tesTest) {
        tesTest.add(raqueta);
    }

    public boolean isInRaqueta(int keyCode) {
        return  keyCode == up || keyCode == down;
    }

    public void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
    {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == up) 
        {
            raqueta.setLocation( raqueta.getX(), raqueta.getY() - 10);
        }

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == down) 
        {
            raqueta.setLocation(raqueta.getX(), raqueta.getY() +10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente! eso solucionó el problema a la perfeccion. Pero podrias decirme sobre que temas debo leer para comprender tu codigo? ( soy muy nuevo en esto de Java )

Comment: Deberías buscar información sobre ejecución de hilos en java, tal comentaba el compañero. Y además, deberías buscar información sobre desarrollo de juegos en java y captura de eventos en juegos java.